# Displaying only what's entered on the page

Tags: views

I have created a new field within one of the content types that can be entered on the content pages and placed the block into the layout, but it seems to add all the pages content that was entered in on all the pages within that field. How can I filter it, so it only shows what has been entered on that specific page.

Answer (score 1):

On the far right, Under Advanced, for Contextual Filters click add

[image]

Add Content ID, select provide default value, select content ID from URL.

[image]